# How to handle extra header which was failed to read in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: asp.net-core

I'm working on our ASP.NET MVC project and trying to convert it to ASP.NET Core MVC project by creating a new project targeting .NET 6 side by side. It's almost done until we see 500 was returned to specific requests from our customers. And the original ASP.NET MVC project works well to handle them. And we cannot tell which requests are different on the original site.

Both the original and new ASP.NET Core project are deployed on IIS on Windows Server 2022 Datacenter.

I've added `app.UseExceptionHandler()` and `app.Use(async (context, next) =>{})` code to the beginning of the `Configure(WebApplication app)` method and still cannot catch the exception.

What I can see is the IIS log is this:

> #Fields: date time s-ip cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query c-ip sc-status sc-bytes time-taken tag1
> 2024-02-07 04:05:16 192.168.1.2 /home/CheckThreadPool - 192.168.0.1 200 252 1 tag1
> 2024-02-07 04:08:06 192.168.1.2 /api/search - 192.168.0.1 500 145 47 -

And my `Configure` method looks like this:

```
public static void Configure(WebApplication app)
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler(errorApp =>
    {
        errorApp.Run(async context =>
        {
            context.Response.Headers["tag1"] = "tag1";
            
            var error = context.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();
            if (error != null)
            {
                var ex = error.Error;
                await context.Response.WriteAsync(ex.Message, Encoding.UTF8);
            }
        });
    });

    app.Use(async (context, next) =>
    {
        try
        {
            context.Response.Headers["tag1"] = "tag1";
            await next.Invoke();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    });
    // other code
}
```

At the same time, I got the error in the Event Viewer.

> Category: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpServer
> EventId: 2
>
> Connection ID "18158513698363146269", Request ID "4000001e-0000-fc00-b63f-84710c7967bb": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
>
> Exception:
> System.InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.
>
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Infrastructure.StringUtilities.GetAsciiOrUTF8StringNonNullCharacters(ReadOnlySpan`1 span, Encoding defaultEncoding)   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpSys.Internal.HeaderEncoding.GetString(Byte* pBytes, Int32 byteCount, Boolean useLatin1)   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpSys.Internal.NativeRequestContext.GetUnknownHeadersHelper(IDictionary`2 unknownHeaders, Int64 fixup, HTTP_REQUEST* request)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpSys.Internal.NativeRequestContext.GetUnknownHeaders(IDictionary`2 unknownHeaders)   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpSys.Internal.RequestHeaders.get_Extra() at Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpSys.Internal.RequestHeaders.get_Item(String key) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.HostingApplicationDiagnostics.<>c.<StartActivity>b__21_0(Object carrier, String fieldName, String& fieldValue, IEnumerable`1& fieldValues)
> at System.Diagnostics.LegacyPropagator.ExtractTraceIdAndState(Object carrier, PropagatorGetterCallback getter, String& traceId, String& traceState)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.HostingApplicationDiagnostics.StartActivity(HttpContext httpContext, Boolean loggingEnabled, Boolean diagnosticListenerActivityCreationEnabled, Boolean& hasDiagnosticListener)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.HostingApplication.CreateContext(IFeatureCollection contextFeatures)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpContextOfT`1.ProcessRequestAsync()

From [the source code](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/9b9fd77b48aa1a82fdc720258bae91875c4a78bc/src/Shared/ServerInfrastructure/StringUtilities.cs#L19) we can see that the header contains null or was failed to be convert to string by UTF8 encoding.

```
public static unsafe string GetAsciiOrUTF8StringNonNullCharacters(this ReadOnlySpan<byte> span, Encoding defaultEncoding)
{
    if (span.IsEmpty)
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }

    fixed (byte* source = &MemoryMarshal.GetReference(span))
    {
        var resultString = string.Create(span.Length, (IntPtr)source, s_getAsciiOrUTF8StringNonNullCharacters);

        // If resultString is marked, perform UTF-8 encoding
        if (resultString[0] == '\0')
        {
            // null characters are considered invalid
            if (span.IndexOf((byte)0) != -1)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException();
            }

            try
            {
                resultString = defaultEncoding.GetString(span);
            }
            catch (DecoderFallbackException)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException();
            }
        }

        return resultString;
    }
}
```

Now I'd like to know if there is anything I can do to handle such request by ignoring extra headers or else?

Update:
Thanks Jason for the help to analyze and that help to narrow down the problem. Finally we found that it is cause by a module we added long ago and it only works for .Net Framework. We delete the module and the problem is fixed. I will pick Jason's answer since it points to the destination.

Comment: Hi, could you kindly check the answer below, and let me know if it useful to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is obvious, the problem is happening in `HttpSys`, so the UseExceptionHandler can't catch this error.

And we should enable the [Failed Request Tracing Rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/webapps/iis/health-diagnostic-performance/troubleshoot-arr-using-frt-rules) to capture the information about the `HTTP.sys`.

By the way, if you know how to reproduce the issue, then we can capture the http request information in browser.

Comment: Thanks Jason. I'm just back from holiday and have tried for the whole day. Unfortunately, no log was generated under the FailedReqLogFiles folder, do you have more tips for the Failed Request Tracing feature? One more thing, if I catch the stream using Wireshark, the headers and content have nothing special, that's strange.

Comment: Thanks for your reply,@leonardzheng, could you share a minimal sample which could reproduce the issue for me, I will check it tomorrow,many thanks

Comment: @leonardzheng And please hide/delete all the sensitive information,you'd better create a brand new project, it could protect your data safe.

Comment: the Failed Request Tracing works after reinstallation and the error request has header X-Forwarded-For with two IPs which cause the problem. But if I debug with IDE instance, it works well. There must be something wrong with the iis config, do you have any idea?

Comment: Hi @leonardzheng, We are getting closer to the truth, please check if there are rules in the url rewrite? If have, please disable it and test again? If not, [please check if there is ForwardedHeadersOptions in your code ?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/proxy-load-balancer?view=aspnetcore-8.0#forwarded-headers-middleware-order)

Comment: Hi Jason, since the same request can be handled correctly when debugging in IDE, there should not be any code to cause the problem. And I've checked the url rewrite setting in iis and it is empty.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256924/discussion-between-jason-pan-and-leonardzheng).

Comment: Hi @leonardzheng, could you kindly find the application_name.exe file in your publish folder, and double-click it to run the application for testing. This way will use kestrel and can check the issue is IIS related or not.

Comment: I double clicked the exe to run the application and sent the same request and got status code 200 with expected content. So it should be something wrong with the iis?

Comment: @leonardzheng I agree, it's difficult to investigate the issue deeper in forum, you can raise a Microsoft support ticket and get help from IIS Team. Because there will have a lot sensitive informations in your IIS(Windows Server).